# Change Asp.net code behind files already on a server

Tags: asp.net

I need to be able to change code in an ASP.net code behind file that has already been deployed to a server.  However, any changes I make to the code seems to get ignored.  I can make changes to the .aspx file, but not the .aspx.cs file.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to rebuild the site in order for changes in the code-behind to be reflected.  And please tell me you are not putting your code-behind files in your production environment.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must rebuild/recompile your web application project, so you will get the newest .dll file on the bin folder that you need to upload to on the server.

For example if your web application named is **MyWebSite** then when you recompile the project you will find the updated **MyWebSite.dll** file on bin folder.

In your case, if you only updated the aspx file in the term on html tags, you don't need to upload the dll to your server. meanwhile if you do update the code logical on your C# codes then you need to upload the updated dll.